# random in 2D range

Tags: python, numpy, random

What is the best way in numpy to randomly choose `n` points in `d` dimensional space, bounded by different size?

For example, I need random 128 points in a 3D cube of sizes `[10, 20, 100]` - length 10, width 20, height 100.

I seek for a better way (if exists) than looping over `d` and choosing each index separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to get points inside a box are uniformly distributed, for this you can use the numpy directly:

```
ans=np.random.uniform(low=[-5,-10,-50],high=[5,10,50],size=[n,d])
```

Here I took the liberty to center your box in origin, but you can play around with the values.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np
Z = np.random.normal(size=[10, 20, 100])
```

Comment: This is not `n` points in `d` dimensional space, and it is not limited in a box.